# How to give more Java process memory (RAM) to games?

Tags: ram, task-management, processes, multitasking

*I have a developer background, but this is not a game development question.*

I have several games that are struggling to be playable with 128MB of RAM allowed for them in Android. I have a Galaxy S4 (2GB RAM) and 600MB free memory just being there doing nothing while I'm playing those games. The games lag on `dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT` events as I had LogCat open while playing, here's an example:

```
04-13 13:25:30.652      832-836/? 
GC_CONCURRENT freed 8192K, 32% free 90350K/132732K, paused 9ms+23ms, total 364ms
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 336ms
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 282ms
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 105ms
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 103ms
```

Is there any way to allow certains apps, or all of them to run havoc on free memory, for example allowing them to use at least 256MB? I'm pretty sure these games have [android:largeHeap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap) already in their manifest.

Killing other apps won't ever help, so please don't suggest to use a task manager unless it has a "set max memory" feature.